# How can i lock screen click mode.

Tags: android, uiviewcontroller

How can I lock screen UI clicking mode. Just like MX Player
When we press lock button in MX Player. That stopped working every button (like NEXT, PREVIOUS, PAUSE). How can I do that same.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way you can add `yourButton.setEnabled(false);`  then when you want to unlock it again you can add `yourButton.setEnabled(true);`

I hope it helps you.